# MongoDB - do I need to convert string id's I insert manually as a reference to another document into ObjectId(id)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, objectid

Im learning mongodb and I have the following question: In one Schema, I have a reference to another model - Im storing id's of books. I have a books model where I have a reference to other books - saving their id's.

The id's of 'similarBooks' I will insert manually. But id's of the books will be always in the format of

```
ObjectId("1234").
```

If user clicks on the name of book a query will be made - findById. However the id's I manually inserted are just strings, not ObjectId("id") so it wouldnt find the book. What is the best way to handle this? Do I then in my query take the id (the one thats just a string) and convert it to ObjectId("id") or do I not just insert manually the id as string but already convert to ObjectId. If so how? So far I just been adding data for this type of models in 3t studio.

Same question is for writing tests. If i have ids stored as strings, do I convert to the ObjectId ?

Thank you!

```
const bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    similarBooks: {
        name: {
            type: [String] //would be only 2
        },
        id: {
            type: [String]  //would be only 2
        }
    }
    ...
})
```

Comment: You can use the `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` to convert string to `ObjectId`.

Comment: but the schema as I understand doesnt do anything, its just defines the structure and content. so if I say: type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, it doesnt do anything. Since Im adding those ids manually, if I just add a string, it will be still just a string despite the mongoose.Types.ObjectId

Comment: Instead of `findById` you can use the `findOne` method and pass the query filter, for example `{ filedName: "some value" }`.

Comment: I dont understand why? I do want to search with the id

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer on the advantage of saving Id as ObjectId instead of string here. Mainly it saves on space.
[MongoDb: Benefit of using ObjectID vs a string containing an Id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680462/mongodb-benefit-of-using-objectid-vs-a-string-containing-an-id)

So to answer you question, i would always convert that String id to ObjectId before adding it to your similarbooks array.