Does reference with ObjectId in mongodb have an impact on performance?
Currently I store the relationship id by just passing the related model id, for example:
{ 
   "_id": ObjectId("5ff7fcf93e2c5a4462b1e619"), 
   "text": "This is a comment.", 
   "userId": "5ff7fbc93e2c5a4462b1e612"
} 

However, in some examples or tutorials on the internet I see the relationship like this:
{ 
   "_id": ObjectId("5ff7fcf93e2c5a4462b1e619"), 
   "text": "This is a comment.", 
   "userId": ObjectId("5ff7fbc93e2c5a4462b1e612") 
}

Putting the relationship inside ObjectId("5ff7fbc93e2c5a4462b1e612") or simply the direct id 5ff7fbc93e2c5a4462b1e612 , does it make any difference to query performance?
I am not aware of methods to do this test. I would like to know the opinion of those who work with mongodb. One observation is that I'm using mongodb in laravel.

What do you mean by "query performance" and how will you measure it? If you are referring to using the field for lookup, it is going to be costly in MongoDB(even with index), no matter what datatype the field is. What you can do worse is having different datatypes in different collection(e.g. having strings in collection A and lookup the ObjectId field in collection B). You need to perform ad-hoc type conversion and will even slow down the query more.

Thank you, but it didn't help much friend, I don't have that much knowledge. In short, I need to know if the query in a relationship would be faster for an objectId or for the string when there is a relationship between models

having ObjectId is better imo. otherwise in cases where you need to do joins you will need to convert the string to ObjectId to compare

Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18680462/21972629
